# URI and package arguments are required while testing mobile browser automation with python and appium

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to run mobile browser automation with python and appium. I am providing required desired capabilities. But after running the script it is returning the error following

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: URI and package arguments are required Stacktrace:UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: URI and package arguments are required
at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
```

My source code is provided below

```
from appium import webdriver
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait



desired_caps = {
'platformName': 'Android',
'deviceName': 'AQE6MVWWAEVOZLTO-r1HMVZ',
'udid': '22e051b70d1783d3',
'appPackage': 'com.android.chrome',
'appActivity': 'com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main',
'showChromedriverLog': True,
 'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
'noReset': False
}
web_driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
# Open a website
web_driver.get('https://www.google.com')

web_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="js-search-autocomplete"]').send_keys("USA")
wait = WebDriverWait(web_driver, 10)
date = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="js-date-range-display"]')))
date.click()
time.sleep(125)
web_driver.execute_script('mobile: shell', {'command': 'pm', 'args': ['clear', 'https://www.rentbyowner.com']})
# Close the browser
web_driver.quit()
```

Please help me . If there is any something I am missing in desired capability?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `browserName='Chrome',` capability to your `desired_caps` dictionary and see if it works.